# How to connect SMSC server using SMPP from PHP

Tags: php, scripting, sms-gateway, smpp

I am trying to connect SMSC server using SMPP from PHP to send and receive sms.
It would be easy if I can find some good php classes or already built script so that I don't have to bother in details?

so, does anyone have experience with this or at least can suggest me which php class or script to use?

Answer (score 1):

create a web form and use the php script given in http://www.ozekisms.com. study the sms messaging process and about esme server, [smsc server](http://blog.ektel.com.np/2012/01/sms-messages-between-esme-server-and-smsc-server/) to get better idea.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [using PHP](https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp) or [NodeJS (I know the question is for PHP but no harm looking here)](https://github.com/Roave/shorty)

Personally, I feel these two are updated quite recently from this current post date of Sep 2013.

I have tried the NodeJS version and it worked for me in both send and receive cases...